# javascript express.js push data into a mongoose model through the schema's hooks during a save operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

How can i update a model during a save operation inside a mongoose schema hook
I have a model which already have some data, but when I want to add extra data into the a field in the model which has some array, I call the model's data and save into it through a push operation. 
How can I get the push operation into a hooks. 
Please have a look at the code below for example

In express.js I can update a model by adding it to a field through this method

```
ModelName1.find({
    'branch': 'San bernadino'
},function(err, branchDetails){
    ModelName2.find({
        name:'Bryan Smith'
        },function(err, members){

        branchDetails.payments.push({
            date: Date.now(),
            amount: 250,
            member_id : members._id
        })
        branchDetails.save(function(err, result){
            if(result){
                /************************************
                *   how can i get this into hooks   *
                ************************************/
                members.subscriptions.push({
                    date: Date.now(),
                    amount: 250
                });
                members.save();
            }
        })
    })
})


Note that member name Bryan smith already exist. but new data is being
saved
```

I am desirous of transfering the operation into schema hooks

In the schema how can I get that done without having to use new